# why infer with this need destructuration?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

why the case 1 not work ?
it give me so many head hash but from what i understand , it need extra decomposition ?
it a bug ?

```
export type This1<S extends System=System> = S extends infer SS
    ? SS extends System< infer RU >
        ? RU extends [infer M, infer R, infer A ]
            ? [M, R, A, 100]
            : never
        : never
    : never;
export type This2<S extends System=System> = S extends System< infer RU >
    ? RU extends [infer M, infer R, infer A ]
        ? [[M, R, A, 100]]
        : never
    : never
export abstract class System<T extends number[] = number[]> {
    abstract rules: T;
}

export class SystemA {
    declare rules:[1, 2, 3];
    test1( o: This1<this> ): void {
        isTest( o );
        isTest2( o ); // why this not work !? 
    }

    test2([o]: This2<this> ): void {
        isTest( o );
        isTest2( o ); // ok here !
    }
}

function isTest<T extends [1, 2, 3, 100]>( t: T ): T {
    return t;
}
function isTest2<T extends [1, 2, 3]>( t: T ): T {
    return t;
}
```

playground: [tsplayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqALAlgZwIwA8AynKDMAHYAmOcRiO5AtgLz2PBMB8cLdpIctVpYKAM2BQ6RALAAoAJAB+aQKE06DZgTiiJUgEoBVOF3kLlcY2soaA2nslwAsgBpd4pwfeOpAQTgAXXMLFTs3K3c-dzwABljgxQsALjgKYAA3SRDU9Kyoc1zMyQBueVBIWARkVExcACZiG2FNDlZ2Zh4+EjJbWg7OHV8rEzNFFWtelodPKQjh7w99OADE0Lg7cPdF6Lg4hLWFIvzCtOKCuQroeABDACNGKBuAY3hngBsbnH6tQbRmjQUACuTDukjsgV4aRBYKgEJ4AG9zPdHi94FAge9gDhUmgynIAL7ycrga5wD5fH5tAJIxRUYAUqCoDFYnF2PDueruADMgXxCnIjDwAAo4BBcdh8AQYJKeABKVIZCBYKhwWkWXBobEwUUQOBy-kKTXa+q6-UlOAAektgF4NwCn+3AAO4YRAISVpCDwR3QADWcAAhCpzES5OZBTBTXYIIEJQ1pbL9Yrlar1UacFrGGaDSFjYxTWLzVbbYAj-bFfowklQ-uD8hD8jEQIorywEAounT2oI-ym9g5cC5cG5MXigS4opguMT6DV5iZMCBUDbMHxIYbTZgLbbuYjXYBtHZnJ5o-Hk4V0-Vc4XS5XQA)

Comment: You're doing some fairly complex type juggling and not explaining it. I assume you're just running into a limitation of TS's heuristic rules around generics (`this` is implicitly generic, you can change it to `S extends SystemA` and see the same behavior), conditional types (like `Test1` and `Test2`), and indexed access (what `test2` is doing to get the type of `o`). Indexing tends to widen generics to their constraints, so in `test2` you're getting `[1,2,3,100]` for `o`, whereas in `test1` it's staying unevaluated and unsoundly allowed to be assigned to `[1,2,3]`. (see next comment)

Comment: (see prev comment) To find exactly *why* would probably be a deep dive into the compiler and/or github issues, but I'm not inclined to do this for the question as it's currently written. Could you please [edit] to clarify why you're doing this and how it's supposes to work, so that future readers could possibly understand it?

Comment: Hello, thank you, and glad that you are still active @jcalz! 
Yes, I apologize for the ambiguity.
I was a bit exhausted when writing it.
I've been trying for three days to find different patterns, but I only come across limitations.
I will take a day to think about how I could formulate the question correctly without introducing too much complexity, and I will add a new playground. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, sounds good. Note that I might not have any amazing insight even so; see issues like [ms/TS#55733](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/55733), [ms/TS#56377](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56377), [ms/TS#32066](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32066); the type checking for generic conditional types and generic indexed access types is often incorrect.