# Anonymous static class infer composition no infer correctly

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, static-methods, type-inference, entity-component-system

i get weird behavior here,

- if i assign a default array in generic of `Compositor<CT extends ComponentType[]=[]>`
- ts keep infer `ComponentType[]` instead of `[]` to my type `SystemWithRule` !

this make not sense for me !?
any help are welcome

- i expected `this.rules` to be infered like this : `[typeof ComponentA]`
- and not like this : `[ComponentType<Component> | typeof ComponentA]`

What i miss ?
**thanks for your time!**

```
type Constructor<T> = new ( ...args: never ) => T;
type ComponentType<T extends Component=Component> = Constructor<T>
abstract class Component {
    declare _: never;
    declare constructorType: ComponentType<this>;
}

export type SystemWithRule<T, C extends ComponentType[]> = T extends Constructor<System<infer CC>>
    ? [ ...CC, ...C ]
    : never;

abstract class System<R extends ComponentType[]=[]> {
    static behavior( behaviors?:'update'|'dirty'|'input'|'none' ) {
        return class Compositor<CT extends ComponentType[]=[]> extends System<CT> {
            static hasAny<C extends ComponentType[], T>( this:T, components:C ) {
                return class extends Compositor< SystemWithRule<T, C> > {
                    static override hasAny:never;
                };
            }

            static hasAll<C extends ComponentType[], T>( this:T, components:C ) {
                return class extends Compositor< SystemWithRule<T, C> > {
                    static override hasAll:never;
                };
            }

            static hasMaybe<C extends ComponentType[], T>( this:T, components:C ) {
                return class extends Compositor< SystemWithRule<T, C> > {
                    static override hasMaybe:never;
                };
            }
        };
    }

    declare rules: R;
}

class ComponentA extends Component {
    declare private __: never;
}
class ComponentB extends Component {
    declare private __: never;
}

// composing systems class with custom rules: ts will AUTO infer composed rules to entities in the systems (no need duplicate interface/inplemebtation)
export class SystemA extends System
    .behavior( 'update' )
    .hasAny([
        ComponentA,
    ])

    // .hasAll([
    //  ComponentB,
    // ])
{
    update() {
        // entity should: should [typeof ComponentA | typeof ComponentB] and not  [ComponentType<Component> | typeof ComponentA | typeof ComponentB] !
        // i cant found where the [ComponentType<Component>] was infer!?, because default generic was empty array [] !!!?
        this.rules; //  
    }
}
```

[tsplayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oDwAqAfFALxQIQDuUAFFAHRMCGqA5kgFwUQBuEqKAEoyJAgG4AUKEiw4AWzCIICYAXARCUCAA9gKgCZI5i5atLxTlVSXLxkaLDnzFJzAEYpUzbFEwAbZiRjSyVrYCgAb0kASAMIANZoAH1uSn5UKTiEwNRoTEQvJ1x1SG5QszUNPGAACwBLJCIpAF9JaQ0oAGUQFAh5AHV6uoAldH9NAgAaWG09QxCFMJUqyABtAF1bKAI5-QQjOQcMbFw8Hr75PHqEADMBWBgiIkkAeleoT6-vn9+--4BgKBwL+AD0APyxcFQNaMJgwGAzJgMGBQDaxNJ8ARSNyeNA+CKJYLdXr6K4jPYLEzLVSlCCbUibEjRGIoZjAeqYKDuCC1Zi8eq4eg8vkC3BIcGcADk6DABnZEClAB8pQZ6qhQMqpTcwOhgFqEMopcIorEYnlgOhUAg-IFiRUkMMzjBdrp9ocKuE6QymZSDsYLmS8C7mWbWcB2ZyoHykABBBAgYN+j1LSrejYzYj0OqNTjTPyp8JcVEiFkxcsWq02onGN1Uh1O-Aky5DUbjSYzJ5QUPl3tsjlcuAZVD1eLRoLxkCcdLYsMxFpZcttMP9qMx2P+fxJuv+6lpjSbTNEbMNLj5gpWFbFk1lisQS3W21BWvzXcN5x4Ztk1u1MYTQidiQPa9uGkaDsOo7QOum7TlimRzguYbLn2EYDuOSAALLMCAPLbq+KaXrSB4Zjsx5QDmZ4zBeNLANepZzpWj41smiymI6H5fv0P5-h2sBAaaIGgWhQ4CCOY4xlhOEQLBGSLkucltPJsTIfEiR5FAGATFwUAjK07TMZ6Kyxixe7hAJqm5NAYAjrwCpQMkqQ8LJkhtAZhYrAAQiZhmqOZORJFA1n1LZ+j2Y5M7wcu7wFmxNxsFASCkv0xjMVQwy1H46AoAoGnttptFQGlm5QLGACqBAAPJQDc9yCNRcBIBABi5Vp5FwNoqjDPUEDGDc5G1NAiWXMYtCGjwTVQAYsr+Jydk3PoqC3D4ECvDqEzyBA7ioYKCBCJIuhKBqT7EoG-TGTuhynfIsQMCK-KCqg9AynKCrGntMQMOuCa0GsZo+cAsZTLEGx7bE0WfROm4-WDHwxP9HlAzE0Ug5ILKyvK+i0PR5bRY10AzZQUAAIwAOzlKm7FnJxgzpTxAF8d2UBmrjtRwOMzVrDIEBwLcplGVASrkRoPN86oHkbFAzAHBQcARDC-10sG7k2ALQuQCL-3GYLXMa8rwDi1AACEzMfPUfhSxEtxs9LVADepdTQGsCvVP9RAS1QQTVXcAiG+CMw8pgzBZdA8RLeMERsCoAhRh7taKKAkuoN4IAwhLhvp5C5YUQwmk9eIUDRYAvBuACy7TM4x8XwQspLlAA)

V2 SIMPLIFIED: [tsplayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/PTAEBUE0AUFEGVQFVwEkAyqoCgAuBPABwFNQBhAewDsBnXAJwFcBjXC+gHnAD5QBeUFWIB3UAAoAdFICG9AOY0AXIOIA3YvQCU-XuADceIqUoBbQtWJVc4I11DEAHrksATGuQpmLV-h69CrXgFKWgYWNk4ebGkAIzp6aVZQZgAbaRp3U3MA3FAAb2wASBdiVNlSAH1lIXV6A2LStPpSZmp48PYbEmUs72tbXAALAEsabgMAX2xDElB4fDpiEwB1YaGAJUYU4i4AGnJ7J1dMz2zLfpIAbQBdIIhD5yo3D1CmVnYOecWTDmGqADMNOQyNxuEUAPygS5SCRkMj7GFka5FapqDQGbAgUAAK0YdFANE8pCWhAIyVOfRo2DKGT8ZysAEEHsc6X18kUSmVmqBCPRhqppM5QBUqipapNqWlab0cgAhZlPE7+c7shpc0i8-mCyqimro7BTTFgGgLZwmUAxdLEaJxBiJXI09xfM0cdYK54y85dYg3Xw3XgFIp0QXDZigEzDBx-ORibQFQqFZq4Rj0KhzU1LTbbKmFQ1qpqkJjZ5TrCWS9JOjMmLPEGgcMjupX0i4+65+26N9PfesB6aFYO4UOgQbpBlUfD1gBMnc9Vm9N32PDEQ1GynA+1ayqsSnIk7jRUTxGTqeSUvcjkez2dma2tc+VdWG1ve13oPyoAP-dwIbDFFqfJKYdR3HVFxQPCZ6kNCDpmmLFN3MGhowJKt3EdUBhDWQZkjxNhzSLWtlFwdwMJSFJQAZFAAHlQD+QF6HJLwaGIFxQHw9w2HsKw1mGWsaLTIZSBNb53DEKgKBUZjQBcRhCBSUNtT45x6H+RJiGAP5ZKWYgYm-QdqE0bBHHMegHTPLszSZC8WWvEwigkCMoyoGMDMKLFpBcFjCRMQtb3cQYNFrfZHGkMxtmQ74mWaABHRhhmaFjZ1wJk7JHGgx3wMRLgPRKGV2IprgM+MZJcbVY1VVzjWIUg5KEUAAGYABYegpRCIg4cylkfQYaxfEFQF4A8sRoQYKC2FjLgIEgKH+VkciZAAfUBJuIabZvOWU22kJ5BAoXIoUS716wpHJeEW5bVpy0AzqMC7jvWtsAEJBrAYZki23J-lG7bhH87kBP2u651sRLuDbYR0j4uiHvBfYYlKaQ8VIEoVK2XI5EsDQh3B88zDJWQEnwKFHoe6GDxXGgJDYvRQCxQBeDcAFl2PwTLFQFZgA9cEiimCYgA)

Comment: Is this the simplest demonstration you can make? I don't understand why `Compositor` is an inner class when it doesn't depend on `System` at all.  Could you please refactor to a [mre] with as few moving parts as possible?

Comment: ho, I had already reduced a lot, I will try reduce again and give more explanation

Comment: @jcalz is this help ? i added link upper : V2 SIMPLIFIED

Comment: sry wrong link, i edited it , my bad !

Comment: You can't infer default type parameters, they play no part in inference (See [ms/TS#16229](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16229)). If I were trying to do what you're doing, I'd leverage instantiation expressions as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m0e5GW) (and you also need a `const` type param in there). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz omg good one thanks you so mutch ! i was sure it was a bug :) yes this fully addresse the question :)

Comment: first time a see `const` like this i will need more doc if you can thanks :)

Comment: this is cool , this mean i will can remove my narrow type to use only const ! i was using this tools to get infer tuples [] but with this tips, no more need ! awesome! https://millsp.github.io/ts-toolbelt/modules/function_narrow.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow the need for such complex recursive generic classes with static fields, but I'll consider that outside the scope of the question.

Your problem seems to be that you except `System.behavior().hasAny()` to infer the [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) generic type argument `[]` for `Compositor`, but you're getting the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `ComponentType[]` instead.  This is working as intended, as per [microsoft/TypeScript#16229](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16229). Generic defaults don't play a role in inference. If you need to infer something where a generic type parameter has to be instantiated with an argument to proceed, it will end up being erased by widening to the constraint.  So for a static member of a `Compositor`, the `CT` type argument will be widened to `ComponentType[]`.

I'm not sure the full extent of what you're doing, but if I wanted behavior like this I'd try to leverage [instantiation expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) so that you can instantiate the type argument explicitly.  Maybe like this:

```
abstract class System<R extends ComponentType[] = []> {
    static behavior(behaviors?: string) {
        return class Compositor<CT extends ComponentType[] = []> extends System<CT> {
            static hasAny<const C extends ComponentType[], T>(this: T, components: C) {
            //            ^^^^^ const type param 
                return class extends Compositor<SystemWithRule<T, C>> {
                    static override hasAny: never;
                };
            }
        }<[]>; // <-- instantiation expression
    }    
    declare rules: R;
}
```

Here the `Compositor` class that's returned will automatically have its generic type argument resolved to `[]`.  Then subsequent calls should be properly generic as expected.

Oh, I also needed to give your `hasXXX()` methods a [`const` type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) so that when you call them with an [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals) like `[ComponentA]`, the compiler interprets this as a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), so that your [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) concatenations work as you expect.  This is mostly off-topic, but it's an issue you would run into after solving the instantiation issue, and I didn't want to have the question digress too much.

Let's test it:

```
export class SystemA extends System.behavior('update').hasAny([ComponentA]) {
    update() {
        this.rules;
        //   ^? (property) System<[typeof ComponentA]>.rules: [typeof ComponentA]
    }
}
```

Looks good. The type of `rules` is `[typeof ComponentA]`, as you expect.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oDwAqAfFALxQIQDuUAFAHSMCGqA5kgFwUQBuEqASjIkCAbgBQoSLDgBbMIggJgBcBEJQIAD2BKAJkhnzFyskYWVlJcvGRosOfMXFMARilRNsUTABsmSIbwxpbAUADe4gCQehB+LNAA+lyUfKgSMXH+qNCYiB4OuKqQXMEWSipqeMAAFgCWSEQSAL7i2gqoYVLQAMogKBCyAOp1tQBK6L7qBAA0sJo6+kFy5crFEADaALrWUAQLuggGMnYY2Lh4fQOyeHUIAGb8sDBERNEA-FAbjPQwMHM-GBbaIpXj8CQudxoLxheKBKBXXQ3MYHJbmEyVSDbMzbEiRKIoJjAOqYKCuCA1Jg8Oq4WjkynU3BId5cDx3VhCfFRHLAdCoBA+fzwspwJCjC4wfbaQ7HEWhdbY8i41FHQyIwZ4SV46JRAnAIkkqCUpAAQQQIDweTs82laLlFQVWzmxFotQaXFmPhWGM4sE5Ot1PL5ArhhltqvRYscl36SJG40m0zmL21urThOJpLgaVQdViRoCZpAoLSGTTzTLUVauuaeFxGVa0Vi8RyUAwU19Yxa4nEofRoRNKtl3tCESbWQSUDAuZ4RKSyW4pfErXauFhQrVscGg-Dx3Vsno9KpNNQtAA5OgwHo52eBPRjUXaBt7coTVt-VFL9fdLQP1E3Ug9DthASBlgA9GBUBQQAep8tDTnAkCdCAQj7nW3RwPc-YVG+RBAYmvobBhWEvsAb7RK0zRAA)

Comment: thanks a lot for documentation it will help, your awesome.
The usage of this pattern if for migrate my curent design with more readable things. It related to many ts lacking and issue and this avoid me to duplicate declarations in ts and js ! more related info here with those broken pattern 1:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77892502/why-infer-with-this-need-destructuration
2:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77994186/how-allow-tuple-generic-to-union-generic